# How can I make suggestions to Ubuntu developers?

Tags: video, photo

Is it possible to make a suggest button on the Ubuntu menu to write here and make a suggestion to the developers?

I have some suggestions for Shotcut (video editor) and Shotwell Viewer.

Answer (score 2):

**shotcut** has a [forum](https://forum.shotcut.org/), where you can post suggestions.

On the gnome [shotwell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Shotwell) developer site you will find all contact addresses under the topic **Getting in Touch**.